# Problem with tailwind css responsive flex direction

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I've been working on a side project to learn tailwind css and i'm facing an issue with the responsiveness of my flexbox direction.

From what i've read you can make an html tag responsive by adding `sm: md: lg:`
so it will use the corresponding class based on the screen resolution. But when i try this with flexbox it doesn't work.

This is a piece of my code: `<div class="flex-col md:flex-row h-screen w-screen m-3">`.

As  you can see i want to use flex-row on a screen larger than `md:`. But it keeps using `flex-col` even when i exceed the `md:` resolution which is 768px.

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-hoover-lr93g?file=/index.html

This is how it looks when i remove `flex-col` and only use `flex`: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR4C4.jpg

Comment: It has nothing to do with flex-col md:flex-row because if you will check debugger then styles are changing correctly. It's hard to help here because codepen uses undefinied colors so everything is just white.

Comment: @chojnicki I moved the project to another site which is working now. https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-hoover-lr93g?file=/index.html

Comment: Now much better ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot use flex-col or flex-row (and other flex classes) without "flex" alone. Class "flex" corresponds to "display: flex" (without it your divs are blocks) and "flex-row" is "flex-direction: row" that will not work without flex display property.

Check the docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction

So instead

```
<div class="flex-col md:flex-row h-screen w-screen m-3">
```

should be

```
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row h-screen w-screen m-3">
```

Fixed code: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-framework-lxz8y?file=/index.html

Also modify widths on smaller devices the way you need them.